# How to decrease the number of cells that are selected in the formula in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office, cells, microsoft

I'm using the `AVERAGE` function and drag/expand it along one row (e.g. from A1 to D1), the cells that are selected should decrease by 1 row in each new column.

For example:

```
A1  
=AVERAGE(A2:A10)

B1  
=AVERAGE(B2:B9)

C1  
=AVERAGE(C2:C8)
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can type the following formula into A1:

```
=AVERAGE(A$2:INDEX(A2:A10;10-COLUMNS($A$2:A$2)))
```

And drag this into the rest of the row (up to I1).

What this does:

- The COLUMNS function will count how many columns you have progressed (starting from 1);
- The INDEX function returns a reference to the last cell in the required range (A10, B9, C8, ...);
- The AVERAGE function then runs on the range A2:A10, B2:B9, C2:C8, etc.